# Using Java 8's stream() gives subclassing error in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: playframework, java-8, ebean, playframework-2.3

In my Play Framework 2.3.7 Java app I have written a method that contains the following expression:

```
myList.stream().map(x -> x.myMethod()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This produces the following error:

```
Entity type class models.MyClass is not an enhanced entity bean.
Subclassing is not longer supported in Ebean
```

If I replace the expression with the pre-Java 8 version of this, it works perfectly:

```
List<SomeClass> myNewList = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
for(AnotherClass x : myList)
    myNewList.add(x.myMethod());
```

What is going on?

Comment: Do you use `Ebean` to access your persistence layer?

Comment: Doesn’t seem to be the first time that using a lambda expression causes this error: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27933056/2711488

Comment: Mon Calamari, yes, I use Ebean. And Holger, I guess you are right. Seems like a quite strange error, though. Still hoping that someone knows what it's about, because I really don't understand it.

Comment: It might help to know what type `x` is. Out of curiosity, does it give the same error if you use the method reference? IE `myList.stream().map(XType::myMethod).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Steve K: `x` is a homemade type called MoneyTransaction, which has a BigDecimal field called `amount`. `myMethod` creates a new `MoneyTransaction` which is a copy of current but with this field negated. I tried doing what you suggest, i.e. write `myList.stream().map(MoneyTransaction::myMethod).collect(Collectors.toList());`, but it results in the same error as the one described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using EBean for your models/persistence, I believe currently you cannot use any Java 8 features within your models (with Play framework):

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1220

It might initially be an anti-pattern to do so, but you could pull the Java 8 features out of the model and put them in some utility class, etc. then your code should work just fine.

Comment: Too bad. But thanks for clearing this up. I will look for updates to Play Framework to support these Java 8 features.